# C# generating excel file and writing to cells

Tags: c#, excel

I am working on a project that runs MySQL queries on DB. I need to feed out the results to a excel sheet that I will be generating on the fly. I had started the code, using msdn tutorials as well as information I found on stackoverflow, however running the application leaves me with

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

At this point I just have the basic code started as I wanted to make this work before I started creating the entire spreadsheet in the code.

```
                    var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    excelApp.Visible = true;
                    Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
                    ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Cells[1, 1]).Value = "Print Date:";
```

If I can provide any more info just ask. I greatly appreciate any information or insight you can provide me with!

Comment: I would like to inform you on this: If the application you are working will be used without someone attending it at all times (e.g. a server), you will eventually run into problems. Microsoft doesn't suggest it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Thank you for your input, but the program will be run by users as needed, no automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that `workSheet` is being set to null as `excelApp.ActiveSheet` doesn't exist yet.

Here's some code that'll create a worksheet object you can use...

```
var application = new Application();

var workbooks = application.Workbooks;

var workbook = workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);

var worksheets = (Sheets)workbook.Worksheets;

var worksheet = worksheets[1];
```

A few things to note when working with Excel:

- Release every object with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object)` when you're finished with it.  If you don't, Excel won't exit when you're done.
- Don't use double-dot references (i.e., object1.object2.value).  If you do you can't release it properly as above.
- Indexes always start from 1, not 0 (in my experience anyway).

Comment: +1 for the "two dots" rule. It's worth noting that all references can also be set to `null`, which will help with garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is, you have not created any worksheets in the Application.
Try doing this.

Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;

newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets.Add();